# Lastest news for classes zfcuser, bjyauthorize and orm

Tags: zend-framework, zfcuser, bjyauthorize, zfdoctrine

I am working with zfcuser, zfcuser-doctrine-orm and bjyauthorize but I'm not sure on how to handle all the configurations. I have setted

```
return array(
    'bjyauthorize' => array(
        // default role for unauthenticated users
        'default_role' => 'guest',
        // default role for authenticated users (if using the
        // 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\AuthenticationIdentityProvider' identity provider)
        'authenticated_role' => 'user',
        // identity provider service name
        'identity_provider' => 'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Identity\AuthenticationDoctrineEntity',
        // Role providers to be used to load all available roles into Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl
        // Keys are the provider service names, values are the options to be passed to the provider
        'role_providers' => array(
            /* here, 'guest' and 'user are defined as top-level roles, with
             * 'admin' inheriting from user
             */
            'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\DoctrineEntity' => array(
                'role_entity_class' => 'Application\Entity\Role',
            ),

[...]
```

(I am using BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\DoctrineEntity as suggested by @ocramius on [Add BjyAuthorize Roles (using ZfcUser and Doctrine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860030/add-bjyauthorize-roles-using-zfcuser-and-doctrine/14862200#14862200))

But "BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\DoctrineEntity" does not exists in the module and it's not in the factories. I tried to use:

```
'BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\DoctrineEntity' => 'BjyAuthorize\Service\DoctrineEntityRoleProviderFactory',
```

But it does not work:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException' with message 'While attempting to create bjyauthorizeproviderroledoctrineentity(alias: BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\DoctrineEntity) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.' in D:\wamp\www\vidum\src\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php on line 860
```

Does anyone know which is the class for this factory?

Comment: Just wondering if this is still a live issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

The correct class to hook up a Doctrine role provider is

`BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ObjectRepositoryProvider`

You can see an example setup [in the docs](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/master/docs/doctrine.md).